# Make a button create a new tab with different name each time

Tags: c#

I need help with getting the command line to make a button always open a new tab that has a number as the name, and then making the new tab have the number that is one higher than the last one as it's name.

Is it possible to start it of like this?

```
var items = tabControl2.TabPages;
items.Add();
```

Comment: How can the command line make a button?

Comment: @GlenThomas That would be quite  a command, wouldn't it

Comment: Do you have a console app and want to interact with a windows form application? Or simply another process? If so more information would be needed as this requires some dllimport functions and reflection

Answer (score 1):

To add tabs programmatically, you can try this:

```
private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
    TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```

Comment: kinda works... but starts at 11 and doesn't go to 20 but jumps to 110.. Then it goes to 199, then it starts at 1100..

Comment: Thx for the help man :D

Comment: just use (tabControl2.TabCount + 1).ToString(); to print only tabcount

Answer (score 1):

I'm on board with the two answers previously posted - they'll do the trick - but I'd tighten up the code thus:

```
private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages
        .Add(new TabPage("TabPage " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString()));
}
```

Gets rid of the intermediate variables which aren't really doing anything useful, and which you won't use again before they descope.

Comment: Thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

No wait.. got it :P

```
private void button28_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string title = "" + (tabControl2.TabCount + 1).ToString();
     TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
     tabControl2.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
}
```

Just left the name blank ;)

Comment: Do note the difference between variable name, Name property and title Text, though..